# Cookies getting refreshed because of my script

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

```
  ******Cookies.set("recently_viewed",'[1]' , 3, "/");*********
  var productIDArray =  JSON.parse(Cookies.get("recently_viewed"))
  if(productIDArray == null) productIDArray = [];
  productID =  window.location.href.split("product_view/")[1].split("/")[0]
  // alert(productID)
  if (productIDArray.length < 7){
    if (productIDArray.indexOf(productID) === -1) {
          productIDArray.unshift(productID);
          
      }
      
  }
  else{
    if (productIDArray.indexOf(productID) === -1) {
        productIDArray.pop(productID);
        productIDArray.unshift(productID);
        
      }
  }
  
  Cookies.set("recently_viewed", JSON.stringify(productIDArray), 3, "/");
```

So Im trying to execute this script which appends the product id from url to the cookie named recently_viewed. By default this cookie doesnt exist, so im being forced to use the first line which i enclosed in ***

But that keeps resetting the cookie value everytime i reload the page.

Is there any efficient way to do this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `productIDArray.pop(productID);` always removes the last array item ... `array.pop` does NOT take an argument

Comment: okay, but that doesnt have anything to do with the question i asked, the first line of code is resetting the cookies' value. I dont want to do that. Is there any other way?

Comment: oh, `Cookies.set("recently_viewed",'[1]' , 3, "/");` ... then don't do that - seems simple enough that setting the cookie value will ... you know .. SET the cookie value - if that line was put there because `JSON.parse(Cookies.get("recently_viewed"))` causes an error if the cookie doesn't exist, then don't blindly expect it to exist .... `JSON.parse(Cookies.get("recently_viewed") || "null")`

Comment: `JSON.parse(Cookies.get("recently_viewed") || "null")` what does this line do exactly?

Comment: makes sure JSON.parse won't throw an error ... `JSON.parse("null")` (note, it's a STRING, but it doesn't have to be, I just make it a string to be pedantic) returns `null` ... so `if(productIDArray == null)` can fix it .... you can combine the two lines to `JSON.parse(Cookies.get("recently_viewed") || "[]")` (the "[]", this HAS to be a string) for cooler code

Comment: That worked like a charm, can you turn this into an answer so i can accept it. Thanks a lot.